# Paypal sandbox issue "Sorry, the system seems to be down. Please try again later." when place order in Magento

Tags: magento2, paypal-sandbox, magento-2.3

I have setting config in Magento 2 (version 2.3.6) to use payment method (sandbox Paypal). Everthing working two weeks ago util today, I have this issue "Sorry, the system seems to be down. Please try again later."

I have research many time (clear cookie, change Encrypted website payments to Off,...) but don't resolve this issue yet. So I guest paypal's developer do something with their sandbox but I'm not sure.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

reseach many time but don't help anything

Comment: Is an API-based payment method configured in Magento? Probably need more information from its logs. You can also try configuring with different sandbox API credentials from https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/sandbox

Comment: After wait few hours, everything work correctly. I think the problem is come from paypal sandbox. Thanks for your answer anyway.